# IE8 shows empty line after floating elements in contenteditable

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ckeditor, wysiwyg, contenteditable

If you have an element following another element that has `float:left` and turn on contenteditable in IE8, the following element will be precedet by an empty line in IE8 if you turn `contentEditable="true"`.

An example:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" style="float:left">
<p>Some random text</p>
```

in IE8 this will be rendered like this:

[image]

See the line before "Some random text"?

This is especially annoying if you use a wysiwyg-editor because this affects some of its functionality. Also, this creates markup you don#t want. In CKEditor, you can see that the dom-path of that line is in the body, not inside any element.

Answer (score 1):

I reported that problem to Microsoft some time ago and they didn't want to fix it: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/576042/floated-elements-in-contenteditable-can-generate-an-empty-line

The last time that I checked with IE10 pp2 still had the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Manually setting the css of paragraph elements with:

```
    p {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}
```

should resolve this issue.